# reference and primitive prototype values

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I don't understand why the array is shared between two instances while the primitive type is not. Can someone please explain?

```
MyObject = function() {};
MyObject.prototype = {anArray : [],aString : ''};
var c1 = new MyObject();
c1.aString = 'a';
c1.anArray.push('a');
var c2 = new MyObject();
console.log(c2.aString);
console.log(c2.anArray);
```

Comment: The primitive type *is* shared between both instances, but you've overwritten the `c1` object's own value.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable, Arrays are mutable. You're replacing the String, but *modifying* the Array.

You'll get the same behavior between Arrays and Strings if you *overwrite* the Array instead of modifying it.

```
MyObject = function() {};
MyObject.prototype = {anArray : [],aString : ''};

var c1 = new MyObject();
c1.aString = 'a';
c1.anArray = []
c1.anArray.push('a');

var c2 = new MyObject();
console.log(c2.aString); // ''
console.log(c2.anArray); // []
```

So it only makes sense to put an Object or Array on the `prototype` if you're planning on allowing all instances to observe changes to it. Otherwise, just put it directly on the instance.

```
MyObject = function() {
    this.anArray = [];
};
MyObject.prototype = {aString : ''};
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. What is the recommended way to have mutable instance variables then?

Comment: @bradmiley: Keep the Array off the prototype, and assign it directly to the new object in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign

```
c1.aString = 'a'
```

you are **not** assigning to the `aString` field in the prototype. A new field called `aString` is created directly in the `c1` object and hides the `aString` field in the prototype.

Meanwhile, when you call

```
c1.anArray.push('a');
```

there is no `anArray` field in `c1`, so you're referencing the `anArray` in prototype. You can test this by doing

```
c1.anArray = new Array();
```

and note that a new property `anArray` is created in `c1`, not interfering with `anArray` in the prototype. In this case,

```
console.log(c1.anArray);
console.log(c2.anArray);
```

would have different outcome, as `c2` would still refer to the `anArray` in prototype.

If there is a field with the same name both directly in the object and in the prototype (or even further in the prototype chain), and you request a value of this field, the interpreter first looks directly into the object, only then up the prototype chain, until it finds the field somewhere.

However, if you assign a value to a field, it is always done directly in the object, never in its prototype.